# How to keep The Form in the Center of the Screen When The Form is Maximized?

Tags: c#

How to keep the Form in the Center of the Screen When The Form is Maximized ?

I tried many codes here on 'stack Over Flow' but nothing worked with my EMPTY form except this code which i have to add to the "public Form1()" method :

```
        Rectangle screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        Point maximizedLocation = new Point
        (
          (screen.Width - this.MaximumSize.Width) / 2,
          (screen.Height - this.MaximumSize.Height) / 2
        );

        this.MaximumSize = new Size(this.MaximumSize.Width, this.MaximumSize.Height);
        this.MaximizedBounds = new Rectangle(maximizedLocation, this.MaximumSize);
```

the problem with is code is when i maximize the form, a black color appears at the corners & the fade around it disappears as well like this :

here is a screen shot :
http://img538.imageshack.us/img538/9208/8zO13l.jpg

Please Help, but explain in detail because I'm a beginner

Comment: Window shadows are not part of the window.  The code is functioning correctly.

Comment: @Dan-o but how to bring the shadows back ? & how to remove that black color on the corners when the form is maximized ? !

Comment: I'm sure you can figure that out.

Comment: @Dan-o thanks, but i really have no idea what i have to do now , sorry

Comment: When you will Maximize a form, it will occupy entire screen. What do you mean by "Keeping it at Centre"?

Comment: it set these properties so the form is not occupying the entire screen when it is maximized :
this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 400);

i mean with Keeping it at Center" is to keep the location of the form at the center of the screen when it is maximized

Comment: check the link of the screenshot to understand what i mean bro. :D

Answer (score -1):

Set the form property.
StartPosition - CenterScreen in the UI

Comment: I did that & it only works with the primary/loading state, but is not working when i press the maximize button at the top of the form's windows (title & control bar)

Comment: try adding an event... form_MaximumSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { -----Set the Property---------  }

Comment: i did that before posting this post ,,, doesn't help :3